# Overriding Named Route Parameters with nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, actiondispatch

I want to override the `:id` param and [this](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-named-route-parameters) explains how. But doesn't really work with nested resources.
My routes look like:

```
resources :users, param: :user_id do
  resources :projects, param: :project_id
end
```

this generates url of format: `:user_user_id/:project_id`. I would rather have it as `:user_id/:project_id`. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
resources :users do
  resources :projects, param: :project_id
end
```

Generate routes like:

```
    user_projects GET    /users/:user_id/projects(.:format)                          projects#index
                  POST   /users/:user_id/projects(.:format)                          projects#create
 new_user_project GET    /users/:user_id/projects/new(.:format)                      projects#new
edit_user_project GET    /users/:user_id/projects/:project_id/edit(.:format)         projects#edit
     user_project GET    /users/:user_id/projects/:project_id(.:format)              projects#show
                  PATCH  /users/:user_id/projects/:project_id(.:format)              projects#update
                  PUT    /users/:user_id/projects/:project_id(.:format)              projects#update
                  DELETE /users/:user_id/projects/:project_id(.:format)              projects#destroy
```

Tested. `Rails  '4.2.1'`

Comment: You did answer my question correctly but I needed more. My project resources has another nested resource `issues` in it. You can tell that your approach will not work in my usecase. I didn't add `issues` for the simplicity of the question.

Comment: @sonalkr132 make a new question and include a full case with a related code.

Comment: hey Зелёный! I have posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32284593/overriding-params-in-nested-routes

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old topic already answered, but as I see there is no explanation for why the code of @Зелёный works and not that of @sonalkr132 (I know this can seem off-topic, but @sonalkr132 posted another question which showed me that he didn't understand how it works)

When you create nested resources like `projects` inside `users`, rails you risk to have a path like `users/:id/projects/:id`, which is nonsense, so rails automatically adds a prefix to the first `:id`, and thus in `params` you have `:user_id` and `:id` (referencing to `:project_id`, but no doubt we are in the ProjectsController, so no further clarification is needed)

Now, when you say `param: :user_id`, this adds together with the prefix `user_`, that is why you get `:user_user_id` - you ask rails do the job twice.